# Substituting all single-non-zero and double-consecutive-non-0 values with 0 in a 3D array without using loops in python

Tags: python, loops, large-data, substitution

Assume M(i,j,k) is a 3-D array, with some non-0 values and many zero values. I want to keep all of the at least three-consecutive-non-0 values, all other non-0 values that do not satisfy this condition must be replaced with 0. i.e:

```
M(:,1,1)=[8,0,1,2,0,3,3,2,0,0,4,7,6,4,0,1,0,2]
```

should be changed to:

```
M(:,1,1)=[0,0,0,0,0,3,3,2,0,0,4,7,6,4,0,0,0,0]
```

This process should be done across j and k without a loop since M is very large.

Answer (score 0):

```
`import pandas as pd
df_test=pd.DataFrame([8,0,1,2,0,3,3,2,0,0,4,7,6,4,0,1,0,2])
df_mask=df_test > 0
df_pass1=df_mask.rolling(3,center=True).sum().mask(~df_mask,0).fillna(0)
df_pass2=df_pass1.rolling(3,center=True).sum().fillna(0)
df_mask2=df_pass2 >= 5
df_test.mask(~df_mask2,0)`
```

If the sequences of three or more non-zero values include the first or the last value in the array we could add a 0 both at the beginning and at the end of the array, and then remove them once everything is done.